# chromecast device recovery issue

Tags: android, chromecast

I am working with `chromecast device`.I am working in android native app. I am in too much trouble with this. I have tried all sample projects that are available on `Github`. Try to make my own app.
here are steps which I follows.

1. GoogleCastSdk
2. mediarouter library
3. AppComp Library
4. Whitelisted My device Properly
5. Set chromecast app as"Send the serial # when checking for updates"..
6. I have also checked that my device is properly whitelisted with `chromecastIP:9222`.

But In every sample or my own app I am facing an issue. `Chromecast` icon is Enabled as there is `chromecast Device`.. But cant discover my device listed there..

Is there any thing that I am missing??

Any help is this case where I am wrong  would be highly appreciated.

Comment: your question seems to have some truncated sentences. In (6), how did you verify that your device is correctly whitelisted? Then, you state "chromecast icon is enabled and there is chromecast device but can't discover my device list there...". What do you exactly mean? Is the cast icon visible on the action bar? If so, what happens when you click on that? Are you putting the app id's correctly? You need to be more detailed than that to get useful help.

Comment: @AliNaddaf its not about 1 sample .. I try all samples... chromecast icon on the action bar is visible. When I click on the icon my device is not found.... .. As u said I also email the snapshot of my screens to u .... kindly check that.

Comment: @AliNaddaf I recived a new Email which contains new App ID.. I replace my older app App ID with new One.. But still stuck in same problem... Can't discover my device....